# getLocation to the center of fusion table layer geometry

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have fusion table that has geometry column, how to get the center latLng of my selected geometry?

This is my fusion table layer code

```
   var testlayer=new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query:{
        select: 'geometry',
        from: 'code',
        where: 'KEC_NO='+number+''
    },
    styles:[
        {polygonOptions:{fillColor:'#FF00FF'}}
           ]
    });
    testlayer.setMap(map);
```

The return of the code above is a single polygon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FusionTablesLayers doesn't zoom to a selected geometry.  You can query the table for the geographic information, create a google.maps.LatLngBounds from that, then center and zoom the map to fit it using google.maps.Map.fitBounds.

[Example (uses GViz to query the FusionTable for KML, then geoxml3 to parse the KML)](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/www_advocacy_ucla_edu_Assembly_MapC.html)

Comment: Solved. .
i use HTML 5 geolocation to get the latitude and longitude of my polygon layer. .
:)